# Interpretar e direccionar com URL que após domínio contém uma hash

Tags: apache, htaccess, hash, url-rewrite, mod-rewrite

Estou a criar uma regra para interpretar endereços que após o domínio começam por `#` seguidos de números ou seguidos de letras cuja regra só deva ser lida se não existir um ficheiro ou directoria que corresponda ao caminho indicado:

```htaccess
# Rewrite the url
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    #DirectorySlash Off
    RewriteBase /

    # se não for ficheiro
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # se não for directoria
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # regra se começar por # seguido de letras com -
    RewriteRule ^#([a-zA-Z])/ index.php?mod=books&slug=$1 [L,PT]

    # regra se começar por # seguindo de números
    RewriteRule ^#([0-9]+)/ index.php?mod=books&id=$1 [L,PT]

</IfModule>
```

A ideia que estou a tentar implementar visa direccionar o visitante para o ficheiro `index.php` na raiz do domínio se o mesmo está a tentar aceder a um conteúdo especifico que pode ser identificado pelo ID do mesmo ou por uma Slug do seu nome:

## Objectivo

Em baixo dois exemplo do que estou a tentar atingir:

- Se receber uma Slug:

  ```
  http://www.example.com/#as-causas-e-os-acasos
  ```

  direcciona para:

  ```
  http://www.example.com/index.php?mod=books&amp;slug=#as-causas-e-os-acasos
  ```
- Se receber um ID:

  ```
  http://www.example.com/#23
  ```

  direcciona para:

  ```
  http://www.example.com/index.php?mod=books&amp;id=#23
  ```

## Problema

Da forma que está neste momento, não chega nada ao PHP, ou seja, nem tenho a variável `mod` nem a variável `id` ou `slug` consoante o caso.

Comment: Até onde sei, o browser não envia o hash na requisição.

Comment: @bfavaretto Tenho estado a realizar testes no sentido de apurar o que disseste e realmente parece que não consigo lidar com isto da forma pretendida.

Comment: @bfavaretto Trata-se de um site com 3 anos tipo página-única (centenas de sub-páginas com navegação via script / animações CSS). Está agora a ser aplicada uma manipulação do URL, mais especificamente a hash. A ideia é permitir copiar o URL, guardar o mesmo nos favoritos, utiliza-lo em redes sociais, etc e conseguir através desse URL manipulado chegar a um conteúdo especifico na página.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sei se o que você está tentando fazer é possível.
De uma coisa eu tenho certeza:

**O browser não transfere o conteúdo de *hash portions* para o servidor durante as requisições.**

Acho que você terá que processar a requisição inicial direto do browser usando JavaScript. Para pegar o valor da hash usando Javascript usa-se `location.hash`.

Answer (score 3):

Como o @Evandro Araújo disse, o servidor nunca vai receber qualquer conteúdo que venha após o # pois é só interpretado pelo browser. Então não é possível você tratar estes termos com o Apache, você terá que utilizar o JavaScript.

Para pegar o # pelo JavaScript você pode usar a seguinte função:

```
function getHash() {
    var hash = window.location.hash; // pega o que tiver depois do #
    return hash.substring(1); // remove o primeiro caractere que é o # e retorna o restante da string
}
```